# Inheritance Vs Composition for a set of class that dont require testing

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles, object-oriented-analysis

I have a `ApproveCheck` method in the following `Billing` class. This method approves the checks received from the customers with an order number, and it gets matched against the orders to approve them. All these classes don't have any interfaces because they don't have any business logic to test, and directly interact with the Database.

Does this follow SOLID principle? Should I consider SOLID because these classes are not indented to be tested or ever the backend DB will ever change? If I have to consider, how can I refactor this code to achieve SOLID?

```
public class Billing : Payment
{
    public void ApproveCheck()
    {
        var checksReceived = GetUnapprovedChecksReceived();
        var ordersReceived = GetPendingOrdersReceived();

        var unapprovedChecks = ordersReceived.Join(checksReceived, 
            o => o.CheckNumber, 
            c => c.CheckNumber, 
            (o, c) => new { c.checkNumber });

        // Approve the unapprovedChecks
    }
}

public class Payment : Order
{
    public Checks GetUnapprovedChecksReceived();
}

public class Order
{
    public Orders GetPendingOrdersReceived();
}
```

Comment: This quesiton might be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with a rewrite, but I can compare the sample to the definition of 
**SOLID**

- Single responsibility principle - Wikipedia says "...every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class". 
  Not enough sample code to determine.
- Open/closed principle - SOLID leans pretty heavily on having abstract interfaces that can be implemented many different ways. To meet this principle look for clear interfaces and strong documentation.
- Liskov substitution - A first approach is to look at the inheritance hierarchy and ask "Is A a kind of B"?. "Is a Billing a kind of Payment?", "Is a Payment a kind of Order?" If you can answer *yes* to those questions, you are on the right track. If the answer is *no*, then the hierarchy needs to change.
- Interface segregation. What are the interfaces? I'm not an accountant, but the model seems off. From the little bit I see, I would model a check as a Payment or PaymentMethod. The hierarchy might be Check : NegotiableInstrument : PaymentMethod. I would probably use it to generate a Receipt, which is evidence of payment. The Receipt is the class that would interact with an AccountsReceivable module. At some point, this will probably have to tie into a reconciliation process where the receipt gets marked as "reconciled" or "returned" (if the check bounces). A real accountant could tell you more.

**UPDATE:**

- Dependency Inversion - If the classes go straight to the DB, there is no chance to invert dependencies. Instead, imagine an abstract class like Account or Repository. The Repository class has methods for querying accounting objects like checks. There will be at least one concrete implementations of Repository, but there could be many. For example, one implementation might connect to a SQL database (e.g. MySqlRepository class). Another implementation might read check objects out of a file (e.g. FileRepository class). A third implementation might send REST requests to fetch checks from a cloud provider (e.g. YoyodyneCloudRepository class). The important thing is that code that needs the checks is written against an  interface or abstract class. That way, it is easier switch in different data sources. The classes that need to use checks do not need to change when the actual repository changes.

From what I've seen in the past, SOLID code needs a framework of abstractions that interact in a defined way. For an example of an accounting model that uses high level abstractions, have a look at some of Martin Fowler's stuff. https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/accounting.pdf. That might be more general than your case warrants, but it is a good place to start reading.

Comment: The _D_ in SOLID is **Dependency Inversion**, which is not quite the same as Dependency Injection. See: https://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html#YouMeanDependencyInversionRight

Comment: @jaco0646. Thanks! I'll update my answer with a correction.